# Can you derive the explicit form of Fibonacci Sequence for arbitrary a0 and a1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I know the Fibonacci sequence can be written as an explicit form when we assume that a0 and a1 both equal 1. But can this also be done for an arbiary a and b as the values of a0 and a1?

Comment: The method is the same. They have the same characteristic equations. Only the coefficients are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we have that the series defined by $a_0=a$, $a_1=b$, $a_n=k(a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})$ has a closed form of
$$a_n=\frac{(a\sqrt{k^2+4k}-ak+2b)(k+\sqrt{k^2+4k})^n+(a\sqrt{k^2+4k}+ak-2b)(k-\sqrt{k^2+4k})^n}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{k^2+4k}}$$
So if $k=1$ then this simplifies to
$$a_n=\frac{(a\sqrt{5}-a+2b)(1+\sqrt{5})^n+(a\sqrt{5}+a-2b)(1-\sqrt{5})^n}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{5}}$$
$$=\frac{(a\sqrt{5}-a+2b)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n+(a\sqrt{5}+a-2b)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2\right)^n}{2\sqrt{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Define a sequence $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ defind by $a_{n}=a_{n-2}+a_{n-1} \, ,\, a_{0}=c\, ,\, a_{1}=d.$ then we can write:$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1}\\ 
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
a_{n}\\ 
a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\ 
a_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}=...=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^n\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1}\\ 
a_{0} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^n\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
d\\ 
c \end{pmatrix}.$$
We got a formula for $a_{n}$ based on $c$ and $d$.

Comment: I'm not sure I comprehend that.. could you rewrite that into an explicit formula? Cause I don't understand how matrices and powers work.